# Zend Form Radio Multioption Title Attribute

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, zend-form

My question is; Is it possible to add a unique title attribute to each radio button on a Zend Form?

My code so far is:

```
$this->addElement('radio', 'vtype', array('label'=>'Type of Visit:'));
$vtype = $this->getElement('vtype');
$vtype->addMultiOption("A","A");
$vtype->addMultiOption("B","B");
$vtype->addMultiOption("C","C");
$vtype->addMultiOption("D","D");
$vtype->addMultiOption("E","E");
$vtype->setAttribs(array('label_class'=>'radio_label'));
$vtype->setSeparator("");
$vtype->setDecorators($myDecorators);
```

Update - This is what I want to achieve if possible:

```
<input type="radio" name="vtype" title="Click A for some reason" value="A" />
...
<input type="radio" name="vtype" title="Click E for some reason" value="E" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do this in jquery:

```
$("#form input[radio]").each(){
  $(this).attr('title', 'Click ' + $(this).val() + ' for some reason');
});
```